# How can I prove the Law of Cosines for the top angle C?

Tags: trigonometry

Look the following image:

[image: a simple triangle]

How can I extract the proof using angle C? It's very straightforward for angles A and B.

I need to reach the following formula:

[image: Formula]

Proofs which I already have:

[image: A]

[image: B]

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you write what your thoughts are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: What about now?

Comment: Well, I guess that's whout the teacher gave to you, regarding the proofs for $\hat A$ and $\hat B$. What have you tried for $\hat C$ so far? Note that the proof you showed are based on $\hat A$ and $\hat B$ being acute. Can you try to adapt the proof to $\hat A$ being obtuse (on of the right triangles would be _outside_)?

Comment: I'm the teacher. I already tried something like that, but without a success. All the books mention about the proof be very similar, so I trying to don't get out of the context too much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key point is to use a different height of the triangle. Turn around the triangle so that you take $b$ as the new base and $h$ as the height from $C$ to $b$:

[image: Triangle]

Now you just need to use the same procedure as above. Consider the right triangles $\bigtriangleup\!\!HCB$ and $\bigtriangleup\!\!HAB$ (again, they both have $h$ in common) and use that
$$\cos\hat C =\frac{-m}{a}.$$
Note that the negative sign is because $\hat C>90º$.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much!!!